# Google GKE Kubelet Configuration

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, configmap, kubelet

How we can configure/use below Kubernetes feature in the GKE clusters.

```
configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy
```

As far I understand Kubelet is managed by the provider. Is there a workaround to use this feature in the GKE? We need to set this value minimum, like 0.

Comment: If the provided information was helpful,you can check this link. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy** controls how quickly the kubelet observes an update to the configmap or secret. It allows you to configure how pods detect changes in config and secret.

configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy is a mode in which ConfigMap and Secret managers are running. Valid values include:

Watch: kubelet uses watches to observe changes to objects that are in its interest (It's the default option)

Get: kubelet fetches necessary objects directly from the API server

Cache: kubelet uses TTL cache for object fetched from the API server

Unfortunately currently it is not possible to edit the  **configMapAndSecretChangeDetectionStrategy** feature in the GKE cluster and the engineering team is currently working on this. You can have a glance at the [blog](https://ahmet.im/blog/kubernetes-secret-volumes-delay/) written by Ahmet Alp Balkan which explains in detail about the parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.